# Is there a way to suggest a download path within a web application?

Tags: javascript, html, download, chromium

Consider the following case:

In my webpage, I have two links that are used for downloading two distinct files, one for `a.css` and one for `a.js`.

CLIENT_AAA prefers to download the `a.css` file into `/path/to/css/` folder and `a.js` file to `/path/to/js/` folder in his specific computer. CLIENT_BBB will probably use different folders, but it's out of our scope.

Problem is that when this user saves `a.js` and then downloads `a.css`, the browser (Chromium in my case) suggests downloading the new file to `/path/to/js/` folder because that was the last folder used for a download. User needs to click up, select `css` folder and then save the file.

I wonder if I can "suggest" the browser for a valid download folder for that user per link, so when user clicks `<a href="a.css" download>a.css</a>`, browser will open `/path/to/css` folder and when user clicks `<a href="a.js" download>a.js</a>`, it will open `/path/to/js` folder. Is that possible?

Comment: Okay. If you move your comment to an answer I'd like to accept it.

Comment: Yea I will because I thought of something else to add.

Comment: One thought is zip them together and only provide one download link for both

Comment: Adding to what @Pointy already wrote, you have also to consider that you do not know the client folder tree therefore how can you suggest a path to save the file? Whatever you would like to suggest would be based on your assumptions on the visitor folder tree.

Comment: @charlietfl Currently I'm following a similar approach: I'm putting the files in a zip file in any hierarchy I wanted, then suggest user to download it always into the same place (the root of the target project), then extract the contents by overwriting the any existent files. This way user uses the same folder for download by only running `watch "unzip -o foo.zip && rm foo.zip"` command in a separate terminal in the download folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's totally up to the browser. There's no HTTP header to do what you're asking. You can specify the filename in Content-Disposition but that's all.

Consider that if you could nudge the browser towards a particular path, and browsers followed your suggestion, that would let bad people create downloads that overwrite system files with whatever content they want. Of course, people can still do that to themselves, but letting the server direct the browser to a particular full path would be a severe security problem.

Comment: Correct, it might be security flaw.